# How may you solve this problem if there's no cycle in number of prime numbers of n!+5 to n!+13 for n=1 to n=15, n!+k not factorable not => prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> For any integer n greater than 1, [n! denotes the product of all the integers from 1 to n, inclusive. How many prime numbers are there between [15! + 5 and [15! + 13, inclusive?] DO THIS WITHOUT A CALCULATOR, WITHOUT coding, in 2 minutes.

Beyond and including n=5, the left endpoint is not prime.

[6, 7, 11, 29, 125, 725, 5045, 40325, 362885, 3628805, 39916805, 479001605, 6227020805, 87178291205, 1307674368005]: This is the values of n!+k for n from one to fifteen, and k=5

There are 9 numbers from 15!+5 to 15!+13 inclusive.

Case n=1: 1!+5=6

There are three primes if n=1, because you start from 6 and end at 14.

These primes are 7, 11, 13

Case n=2: 2!+5=7.

There are three primes if n=2, because you start at seven and end at 15.

7,11,13.

Case n=3: 3!+5=11

There are four primes if n=3, because you start at 11 and end at 19.

11,13,17,19.

Case n=4: there are two primes

case n=5 there are two primes.

No cycle besides at high enough n, one has zero primes.

It's not true that whenever n!+k where k>n, and k is not a factor of n! you have a prime

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. It's only about $15!+k$, not about $n!+k$ for all $n$ from $1$ to $15$.

Comment: The parantheses are confusing. I think in the original text it is first explained how the factorial is generally defined. And then , it is only asked how many primes the interval $[15!+5,15!+13]$ contains. This is however an almost trivial task. If it is required for every positive integer $n$ upto $15$ however , two minutes is very little time although many possibilities can immediately be ruled out.